# Folder full of .jpg files. Batch convert each to a video with duration of X seconds

Tags: ubuntu, batch, video-conversion

I am looking for a way to mass convert a folder of image files to a video (one per image), where each of the images is taken and placed on the video for the full duration of the video, e.g. 30 seconds.

Is there a way to automate and - if possible - multithread this task?

Using Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, you can do this but the process varies between the different NLE's. What NLE are you using to edit the video?

Comment: Which operating system are you working on? Are you looking for one video of 30 seconds for each image, or a 30 second video that has each image in the folder for an equal portion of 30 seconds?

Comment: @JasonAller Each image should be represented by a single video, so if the folder has 100 images, the result should be 100 videos with 30 seconds length each and each video having a unique still image for the duration of the full video.

Comment: @ZviTwersky Tried with Kdenlive, but I still have to do the drag and drop stuff manually. It is good generally because it supports multicore processor encoding and you can schedule projects to convert one after another, but there is no command line to automate stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ffmpeg for that. Example for 1 image to a 30 sec video would be:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img.png -c:v libx264 -t 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

Now you can loop this code in a batch file. Here's more documentary on other ways to use ffmpeg for images:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images